# How do I extract all the features from a pcap file using Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, feature-extraction, pcap

Hi its my first time using this, I have a PCAP file and I need help to extract all the features from this. When I open it in wireshark and export it as .csv all i get is the default columns which aren't useful.

Can anyone guide me to how I will go about doing this? I've seen some people mention TShark but haven't been successful in finding something useful which provides a tutorial on how to do this.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on `extract all the features`:
Do you want to extract certain features from all TCP packets (per se), or do you just want to export the whole analysis on the packet in Wireshark?

Comment: Hi @ELKozel Thanks for the response. Theres an Online dataset which contains a preprocessed CSV and a pcap file which should enable me to engineer my own features. I'm struggling with the "engineer my own features". The user of the dataset used AfterImage Feature Extractor which is a .py script which i have knowledge how to do and when opened in wireshark and export as csv. It only displays 5-6 features which cant be used for Machine Learning models on R Studio as they're not in numerical form.

Comment: Hi @Sami Longsdale, sorry for my late answer, but I am still confused :(. 

What does the CSV contain and what does it mean to "engineer your own features"? Do you want to manually do this process, or automate it? 
From what I understand, there is a CSV that shows you what data needs to be extracted from the packets in Wireshark in a CSV format, am I right? 

Maybe it takes somebody smarter than me to answer your question :(, but I will try my best ...

Answer (score 1):

Tshark can do that using the following instruction:

```
  tshark -r (path of pcap file) -E separator=, -E header=y -T fields -e field1 -e field2... > name.csv
```

The above code will read a pcap file, extract the features (fields) and output a CSV file.

**-E header= y**: if you want to have the name of features in the output CSV files.

**-e field**: The feature to be extraced.

The list of the fields/features can be long to be mentioned here. You can select the features from this tshark link https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/#section_t, based on the protocol.

You can also use the list in this link https://medium.com/hacker-toolbelt/wireshark-filters-list-983c49468a45.

Example: Extract IP address (source and destination), Protocol, MAC address (source and destination) from a PCAP file and output a CSV file.

```
tshark -r Data\myfile.pcap -E header=y -E separator=, -T fields -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e ip.proto -e eth.src -e eth.dst > Data/myfile.csv
```

**myfile.pcap**: name of pcap file in Data folder.

**myfile.csv**: name of csv file, you don't have to creat this before running the code as it will be autimaitcally created in Data folder. you can select the location you want.

Comment: tshark can be found in the Wireshark Installed Folder inside C Drive for Windows.